# Extrude Inclined 3D Boreholes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene, borehole, subsurface

I need to extrude the 3D Borewell data using the inclined angle in ArcScene. I've seen only the options for extruding them in one direction(i.e., perpendicular downwards  or upwards). I got point data with Direction, distance and I need to use both the attributes for extruding below the surface.

Comment: On a side note, you have 7 other questions that people have provided some good answers for. Would it be possible to mark some of those questions as answered?

Comment: I second @dassouki. Your participation and feedback is important. What you need to do cannot be done in ArcGIS using out of the box tools but it can be done programatically. Better option is to use different software where this is a basic function.

Comment: Ramakrishna, you have indeed been gracious in offering thanks to your respondents, so nobody is questioning your intentions.  As long-time members of this community, Jakub and Dassouki value the *formal* feedback that people provide in terms of accepted questions (and votes): they know these provide useful cues to future users (such as yourself) concerning the quality of the answers you can find on this site.  The mechanism for accepting an answer to one of your questions is simple; if you need more information, feel free to ask in chat, meta, or even in a comment.

Comment: This Question has had no activity for about 18 months.  Would you be able to edit it to indicate what version of ArcGIS for Desktop you are currently seeing it in, please?

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit I have never done any sort of 3D GIS but a quick look at the ArcObjects API suggests this can be done?

There is an interface called *IExtrude* and it has a method of [ExtrudeAlongLine](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m000001n8000000). Calculate that line's direction and angle and I believe it could be used to extrude a point.

Examples of using the *IExtrude* interface are found [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000m6v000000).