# Extruding at angle in ArcScene?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene

Is it possible to extrude an an angle other than vertical in ArcScene?

I am trying to visually display some mine adits that cut between two layers at an angle of 30 degrees.

Comment: Maybe you can do it using some mathematics in expression builder

Comment: I don't do much 3d work but may be you can draw the adit with Z values for its vertices then buffer it using the Buffer 3D (3D Analyst) tool? This will of course create a tube rather than a rectangular passage.

Comment: We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Answer (score 1):

I would extrude the feature vertically then rotate the feature along the axis you want (https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/3d-analyst/rotating-a-feature-in-3d-using-the-rotate-command.htm
). Then I would remove/sculpt out sections of the feature that are inaccurate, using vertex editing (https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/3d-analyst/vertex-editing-in-3d.htm).

You may also want to refer to a previous post that discusses using ArcObjects for this: [Extrude Inclined 3D Boreholes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21025/extrude-inclined-3d-boreholes). This would require the use of code and the IExtrude interface.